# Does overloaded cast operator for a class allocate memory or does the compiler optimize it?

Tags: c#

Let's say I'm writing a wrapper over an int type. I implement the cast to int operator, but then I need to implement cast from int as well, in order to get this wrapper cast to be used with assignments exactly like an int.

Is there any way to implement the cast from int operator without returning a new instance of our class? Or, is implementing like that actually allocating new GC memory or is the compiler smart enough to optimize it?

More details: the class itself tracks whether the value changed (for user interface purposes), so it's not simply a value type, conceptually.

Typical implementation looks like:

```
public class MyClass{
  bool m_changed = false;
  int m_val;
  public static operator MyClass(int val)
  {
     return new MyClass{m_val = val, m_changed = true}; // I would think this allocates new memory
  }
```

whereas I want

```
public operator =(int val)
{
  m_changed = true;
  this.m_val = val; // no new memory allocation
}
```

and ultimately I want

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
...
// later that day
obj = 42; // nice painless syntax, with implicit conversion
```

Comment: Show us what you got.

Comment: You can't "cast" an int to a custom type - you are coding a "conversion" operator that must return an instance of a different type, which is likely a new instance.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: don't you just love troll downvotes

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to implement the cast from int operator without returning a new instance of our class?

Sure, return `null` and you won't be returning a new instance of the class.  I suppose technically you could also use some sort of object pool or other similar strategy to return some already-existing object, thereby not returning a *new* object.  That said, from the sound of what you're doing, you'd almost certainly want to just be returning a new instance of that type.

> Or, is implementing like that actually allocating new GC memory or is the compiler smart enough to optimize it?

It's just some syntactic sugar around a static method.  Just like any other method it does whatever you tell it to do in its implementation.  There is no allocation *required* by the pure act of calling the method, but typical implementations are going to allocate an object to return.  There is nothing for the GC to "optimize" here; it's entirely dependent on what you choose to provide as the implementation of the operator.

Comment: What I'm asking for is basically operator = overloading. Is there any way to implement that? Going through the implicit conversion operator requires me to instantiate yet another object, just so that I can set the basic type member it wraps to a certain value, which doesn't make any sense. In C++, you can just override = so that you can set the relevant member of your object instance, without ever touching new memory

Comment: @Zadirion You're free to check the list of operator overloads yourself to see if the `=` operator is on the list.  But really it sounds like you just want to be using a `struct`, not a class, since it seems that the type that you have is conceptually a value.  It should of course be immutable, and you *would* want to create a new instance of it in your conversion operator, as you'd want it to be immutable, just like `int` is.

Comment: It isn't conceptually a value because it tracks whether the value it wraps changed or not (a dirty flag for UI purposes). I did not include that in my question because I expected answers addressing the question itself, not my choice of implementation.

Comment: @Zadirion, you don't want what you want. Nobody would expect it when looking at the code. Is there a reason you cannot do the sensible thing? Expose a property, and update your "dirty" flag in the setter of that property.

Comment: @Zadirion I did answer the question that you asked, exactly, and then you edited the question into a completely different question because you didn't like the answer.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram The user WOULD expect it though, the class is called DirtyInt or something similar. It looks like a duck and I want it to quack like a duck. Nonetheless, your suggestion is the next best thing I suppose. I would accept it as an answer if it wasn't in the coments

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for

```
obj.SetValue(42);
```

rather than

```
obj = 42; // nice painless syntax, with implicit conversion
```

because that makes clear what's happening. With the `=` syntax, the reader would never expect the instance to be retained, even if you found a way to do it.

If you want the value to be visible to the user of `obj`, you could also go for a property. If not, I'd prefer a method, because setter only properties feel weird.